# Share code between Middleware and DelegatingHandler

Tags: c#, .net-core, middleware, code-reuse, delegatinghandler

*dotnet version: 6.0.300*

I am currently writing a custom monitorization feature, that observes requests to all controllers, as well as outbound requests to other apis.

Currently, I have integrated two separate solutions - that practically do the same thing:
Inbound requests are monitored using a [Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0), and Outbound requests are monitored using a [DelegatingHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers). It would be great if I could utilise the same code for both, seeing they are both, in essence, `HttpRequest`s and `HttpResponse`s.

**So my question is**: Is it possible to use a `DelegatingHandler`, to intercepts every controller request. As well as use that same `DelegatingHandler` to intercept every outbound http request?
And if not, is there an alternative way to achieve the desired result? Or am I stuck with having two separate classes (A middleware and a `DelegatingHandler`)

From what I inferred from reading Microsoft's own documentation: they recommend shifting to Middlewares.

> "If your app is using custom HTTP modules or HTTP handlers, you'll need a plan to migrate them to ASP.NET Core. The most likely replacement in ASP.NET Core is middleware." - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/porting-existing-aspnet-apps/middleware-modules-handlers#aspnet-modules-and-handlers

*Thanks for any insight you can provide :)*

## Middleware

```cs
public class MyMiddleware
{
    private const string FailedToReadBodyErrorMessage = "Error: failed to read request body";

    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public MonitorOperationsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    } 

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, IMonitorDispatchService activity, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        var requestPath = context.Request.Path.ToString();

        await using OperationMonitorRequest request = activity.StartRequest(requestPath);

        request
            .SetRoot(requestPath)
            .AddPayload("Method", context.Request.Method)
            .AddPayload("Query", context.Request.Query);

        string requestBodyContent = await GetRequestBody(context);
        request.SetRequest(requestBodyContent);

        await using OperationMonitorResponse response = request.StartResponse();
        try
        {
            string bodyResponse = await GetResponse(context);
            response.SetResponse((HttpStatusCode) context.Response.StatusCode, bodyResponse);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            response.SetResponse(e);
            throw;
        }
    }

    private static async Task<string> GetRequestBody(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Request.Body.CanRead)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        try
        {
            // Enable buffering so the request can be re-read
            context.Request.EnableBuffering();

            // Leave the body open so the next middleware can read it.
            // Leave stream open so next middleware can read it
            using var reader = new StreamReader(
                context.Request.Body,
                Encoding.UTF8,
                false,
                512,
                true
            );

            string body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            context.Request.Body.Position = 0;

            return body;
        }
        catch
        {
            return FailedToReadBodyErrorMessage;
        }
    }

    private async Task<string> GetResponse(HttpContext context)
    {
        /* The response.body is read only, so we need to temporarily convert it into a memory stream,
         so we can read the response value and log it */
        Stream originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;
        await using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        context.Response.Body = memoryStream;

        await _next(context);

        // Read response
        try
        {
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return await new StreamReader(context.Response.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        }
        finally
        {
            // Reset the stream to not interfere with any other possible middlewares
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            context.Response.Body = originalBodyStream;

            // Copy the contents of the new memory stream (containing the response), to the original stream:
            // in order to return the user the original response
            await memoryStream.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);
        }
    }
}
```

## Delegating Handler

```cs
public class MyDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IMonitorDispatchService _monitorService;

    public OperationMonitorDelegatingHandler(IMonitorDispatchService monitorService)
    {
        _monitorService = monitorService;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken
    )
    {
        string requestName = request.RequestUri?.AbsolutePath ?? "Unknown Request";

        await using OperationMonitorRequest monitorRequest = _monitorService.StartRequest(requestName);

        monitorRequest
            .AddPayload("Method", request.Method.Method)
            .AddPayload("Source", request.RequestUri?.AbsoluteUri);

        if (request.Content != null)
        {
            string body = await ReadContentAsStringAsync(request.Content, cancellationToken);
            monitorRequest.SetRequest(body);
        }

        await using OperationMonitorResponse monitorResponse = monitorRequest.StartResponse();
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            string body = await ReadContentAsStringAsync(response.Content, cancellationToken);
            monitorResponse.SetResponse(response.StatusCode, body);

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            monitorResponse.SetResponse(e);
            throw;
        }
    }

    private static async Task<string> ReadContentAsStringAsync(
        HttpContent? content,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken
    )
    {
        if (content == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        return await content.ReadAsStringAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to 1) specify your dotnet version, and 2) show your middleware handler and DelegatingHandler

Comment: @BurnsBA. Hey sorry, I updated the post to say which dotnet version I use :)
But in terms of code, I was thinking more in along the lines of "can it be done", and if so, how would one achieve that? But if you would prefer I could post the code, albeit, it is very boiler-platey

Comment: Maybe it can be done in middleware, it depends on how and what you are doing.

Comment: Hey, @BurnsBA, I added the code snippets :)

Comment: @BurnsBA, got any suggestions?